# Surface 2 tablet: moving apps to sd card triggers errors

Tags: sd-card, windows-rt, surface-2

I'm trying to move the WindowsApps folder to my SD card on my Surface 2 tablet. It's a 32 GB model, and already out of storage. As a workaround (Windows RT forces uses to install only on the built-in storage), I followed the tips at the following post by user274391: 
[On Windows 8 or 10, particularly on tablets with a permanently inserted SD card, is there a universal way to treat the card as a non-removable drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/692151/on-windows-8-particularly-on-tablets-with-a-permanently-inserted-micro-sd-card/692369#692369?newreg=da034dd2fb204cc09f5406f380ebb99b)

Everything went smoothly ... until I tried reinstalling my apps (which I'd uninstalled beforehand).

However, now apps cannot be installed successfully. At first I received error codes: (either 0x80070057 or 0x80073cf0) whenever I tried to install any app I purchased previously.

After rechecking permissions on HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Appx  folder in registry as well as WindowsApps folder, I tried running the Windows 8 App Troubleshooter (no luck). I tried creating a new user profile.  I also tried a System Refresh - now apps install only part way. When I try to open them, I'm prompted to repair the installation - but it doesn't do anything.