# Trying to auto-mount a VHD from microSD results in Error 0x80004005

Tags: windows-8, vhd, automount, windows-task-scheduler, removable-media

I was following the instructions from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/692151/on-windows-8-particularly-on-tablets-with-a-permanently-inserted-micro-sd-card?newreg=0f0469da09c54e35bc3e8c0a959e2660) down to the last detail, however on my Surface Pro 3, all I get when looking at Task Scheduling is an unknown error everytime I boot up my Tablet. Namely it says "Unkown Error (0x80004005).
Looking for the Error online only brought up problems with VirtualBox, which I have no dealings with.
Mounting it manually from Disk Management also still works.

Is there something I did wrong? Anyone else encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what caused this, but doing what I did before, namely putting the diskpart command + arguments into a .bat file and letting this file be executed by the Task Scheduler suddenly seem to have done the trick.

A wild assumption would be that the file couldn't be reached for one reason or the other.