# Is there a way to turn removable drives into fixed ones in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-memory, liveusb

I want to run windows 10 off a live flash drive and I need a page file. It doesn't matter how effective that page file actually is, it is only required to fill a virtual memory requirement for launching a specific program that doesn't actually do anything with it (the way I use it).

Windows won't let that happen of course, it won't let you create a page file on a removable device nor on a VHD (the way the win 10 installation lives on the usb stick).

For windows 7, there is a wonderful kernel hack driver referred to as "diskmod". After installing the driver, all usb drives, removable or not, appear as fixed drives. You can also put a page file on them and everything works flawlessly.

I want to upgrade to windows 10 for its native usb 3 support though since the boot times on usb 2 are terribly long.

Does anybody know of a similar hack or some other method to make win 10 allow page file on a removable device?

Comment: Related to question in title but not necessarily the question in the body of this one: https://superuser.com/questions/692151/on-windows-8-or-10-particularly-on-tablets-with-a-permanently-inserted-sd-card?rq=1

Comment: @Mokubai its similar but the solution is not applicable for me since windows removes the page file from VHD's on boot

Comment: It sounded, at least in part, like what you were wanting to do. I suspected that page file on a VHD or *any* removable disk might be problematic but was not sure about the case of actually managing to boot from USB in the first place.

Comment: @Mokubai I use software called WinToUSB, it makes it pretty easy and has a very wide range of hardware compatibility (from really old to brand new, all motherboards I've tried have successfully booted from my sticks). Also as far as I can tell, the restriction on not letting page file on a removable drive is purely symbolic since I haven't had any problems using the kernel driver to bypass it on windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, you are close. You are just asking the wrong question, fundamentally speaking. You need to use a device that has write-caching enabled, or more importantly, the ability to change write0-caching settings.

The issue with doing custom pagefiles in Windows 10 at least comes from if the device has support for write-caching and SuperFetch, the spiritual successor to Prefetch from Windows XP.